# Getting Wrong Value while trying to find the Volatility

Tags: python

```
covariance_matrix = clean_returns.cov()
temp_list = []

for row in temp.iterrows():
    index, data = row
    temp_list = data.tolist()
    npa = np.asarray(temp_list)
    npa_trans = npa.transpose()
    Portfolio_Returns['Volatility'] = np.sqrt(
        np.dot(npa_trans, np.dot(covariance_matrix, npa)))
```

I expected to get different Volatility Values however the dataframe is showing the same value which is `0.022906`

Comment: please advise what is the value of clean_returns and temp.  please give us sample data to work on.

Comment: We need sample data to reproduce the problem and trying to find a cause.

Comment: hey, I solved it  nvm, It was storing the last volatility value Ive calculated instead of saving each value for each row

Answer (score 0):

the code saves the last value of the volatility calculated in the whole "Volatility" column instead of saving each volatility value in each row

```
       Portfolio_Returns['Volatility'] = np.sqrt(
            np.dot(npa_trans, np.dot(covariance_matrix, npa))
```